# Tracking/Checking WCF client message

Tags: wcf, iclientmessageinspector

I send a message from my client (*implements IClientMessageInspector*) using BeforeSendRequest() and  receive the reply from the endpoint at AfterReceiveReply().

My question is what is the most effective way to "validate" the reply that I receive is in relation to the request I sent?

I found some article about using the correlationstate, but the examples were all too vauge.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, we could use the `Correlationstate` parameter to maintain the value in order to represent the relativity.
That’s why the `BeofreSendRequest` has the returned value.

```
public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
{
    Console.WriteLine(correlationState.ToString());
    string displayText = $"the client has received the reply:\n{reply}\n";
    Console.Write(displayText);
}

public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
{
    var correlationstate = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    string displayText = $"the client send request message:\n{request}\n";
    Console.WriteLine(displayText);
    return correlationstate;
}
```

Here is a related discussion, wish it is useful to you.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c8de85bf-9ffe-478e-a23c-2514a6504bce/iclientmessageinspector-maintain-id-value-between-the-beforesendrequest-and-afterreceivereply?forum=wcf
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Ab...thanks...this helps...what's your opinion about saving a copy of the correlationstate created in BeforeSendRequest() in the Inspector and use it to validate in AfterReceiveReply()?

Comment: You mean that we create a global variable, is that right?  All requests from different clients can trigger these two methods.  I think it might be unfeasible. Assumed that there is a lag in the practical method to be called. the last request will get the latest response.  It might go wrong.

Comment: no, not a global variable, but an instance level property

Comment: The default instance mode of the WCF service is InstanceContextMode.PerCall. There is a new instance will be instantiated in every call unless that we manually specify the service instance mode to InstanceContextMode.Single.